# Web3py: can not find ABI function after decoded

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py

Here is transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6465187a7bb43a6db42ee63e5f5cc30fb094393957a7f1ce6c08b5afddf3e0bc

I don't know why my script can not find ABI Transfer() function after decoded on `Chainlink: LINK Token` address. The main problem is that script works correct, I tested on many transactions and appended 2 of them for example.

Perhaps problem is in Transfer() input params after decoding? But how to solve it?

```py
import requests
import json
from web3 import Web3
from web3._utils.events import get_event_data
from eth_utils import event_abi_to_log_topic
from hexbytes import HexBytes


API_ETHERSCAN = "" # etherscan works without API, you can remove it from url, but make some seconds delay between requests

transactions = [
    '0xff8db775b90935b1ade58182054c0be04f613ea23f9e1df73a6114a726e76237', # Transfer +95352033474036727055914 RIO
    '0x7bdfe6c2a9309773ddeafddc2624edc2b38f13ec257182576d95d8b5f5ea2cd1', # Transfer +29000000000000000000 INJ
    '0x6465187a7bb43a6db42ee63e5f5cc30fb094393957a7f1ce6c08b5afddf3e0bc', # ABI not found. But must be +7,601.747 LINK
]

testnet = 'https://eth.rpc.blxrbdn.com'
#testnet = 'https://eth.merkle.io'

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(testnet))
for t_hash in transactions:

    print(f"tx_hash={t_hash}")
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(t_hash)

    for i, log in enumerate(tx_receipt['logs']):
        print(f" {i+1}) log['address']={log['address']}")
        abi = json.loads(json.loads(requests.get(f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={log['address']}&apikey={API_ETHERSCAN}").text)['result'])
        contract = w3.eth.contract(log["address"], abi=abi)

        event_abi = [a for a in contract.abi if a["type"] == "event"]
        topic2abi = {event_abi_to_log_topic(_): _ for _ in event_abi}
        log_ = {
            'address': None, #Web3.toChecksumAddress(address),
            'blockHash': None, #HexBytes(blockHash),
            'blockNumber': None,
            'data': log['data'], 
            'logIndex': None,
            'topics': [HexBytes(_) for _ in log["topics"]],
            'transactionHash': None, #HexBytes(transactionHash),
            'transactionIndex': None
        }
        try:
            event_abi = topic2abi[log['topics'][0]]
        except KeyError as e:
            exit('ABI event not found!')
        data = get_event_data(w3.codec, event_abi, log_)['args']
        print(f"     {event_abi['name']} {data['value'] if 'value' in data else ''}")
```

Output:

```
tx_hash=0xff8db775b90935b1ade58182054c0be04f613ea23f9e1df73a6114a726e76237
 1) log['address']=0xf21661D0D1d76d3ECb8e1B9F1c923DBfffAe4097
     Transfer 95352033474036727055914
tx_hash=0x7bdfe6c2a9309773ddeafddc2624edc2b38f13ec257182576d95d8b5f5ea2cd1
 1) log['address']=0xe28b3B32B6c345A34Ff64674606124Dd5Aceca30
     Transfer 29000000000000000000
tx_hash=0x6465187a7bb43a6db42ee63e5f5cc30fb094393957a7f1ce6c08b5afddf3e0bc
 1) log['address']=0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA
ABI event not found!
```

Prove:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line to check the structure of `event_abi`

```
print("event_abi['name']",event_abi)
```

I was getting those results:

```
 {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'from', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'to', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'Transfer', 'type': 'event'}

 {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'from', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'to', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'Transfer', 'type': 'event'}


 [{'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'name': 'from', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'name': 'to', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': False, 'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}, {'indexed': False, 'name': 'data', 'type': 'bytes'}], 'name': 'Transfer', 'type': 'event'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'name': 'owner', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'name': 'spender', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': False, 'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'Approval', 'type': 'event'}]
```

first 2 results were `dict` but the third one is a `list`. I was first getting this error:

```
---> 69 print(f"     {event_abi['name']} {data['value'] if 'value' in data else ''}")

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Because `event_abi` can either be a dictionary or a list of dictionaries. To handle this variability, I had to adjust how to access the 'name' key depending on the type of event_abi. so I added this

```
try:
    event_abi_entry = topic2abi[log['topics'][0]]
    if isinstance(event_abi_entry, dict):
        event_name = event_abi_entry.get('name', 'DefaultNmae')
        data = get_event_data(w3.codec, event_abi_entry, log_)['args']
        print(f"     {event_name} {data.get('value', '')}")
    elif isinstance(event_abi_entry, list):
        for abi_entry in event_abi_entry:
            event_name = abi_entry.get('name', 'DefaultName')
            data = get_event_data(w3.codec, abi_entry, log_)['args']
            print(f"     {event_name} {data.get('value', '')}")
    else:
        print("Event ABI entry is not in the expected format.")
except KeyError as e:
    exit('ABI event not found!')
```

and it does not throw KeyError. proof of work:

[image]

This is the full code:

```
import requests
import json
from web3 import Web3
from web3._utils.events import get_event_data
from eth_utils import event_abi_to_log_topic
from hexbytes import HexBytes


API_ETHERSCAN = "YOUR-API-KEY-HERE" # etherscan works without API, you can remove it from url, but make some seconds delay between requests

transactions = [
    '0xff8db775b90935b1ade58182054c0be04f613ea23f9e1df73a6114a726e76237', # Transfer +95352033474036727055914 RIO
    '0x7bdfe6c2a9309773ddeafddc2624edc2b38f13ec257182576d95d8b5f5ea2cd1', # Transfer +29000000000000000000 INJ
    '0x6465187a7bb43a6db42ee63e5f5cc30fb094393957a7f1ce6c08b5afddf3e0bc', # ABI not found. But must be +7,601.747 LINK
]

testnet = 'https://eth.rpc.blxrbdn.com'
#testnet = 'https://eth.merkle.io'

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(testnet))
for t_hash in transactions:

    print(f"tx_hash={t_hash}")
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(t_hash)
    # print(tx_receipt)

    for i, log in enumerate(tx_receipt['logs']):
        print(f" {i+1}) log['address']={log['address']}")
        abi = json.loads(json.loads(requests.get(f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={log['address']}&apikey={API_ETHERSCAN}").text)['result'])
        contract = w3.eth.contract(log["address"], abi=abi)

        event_abi = [a for a in contract.abi if a["type"] == "event"]
        topic2abi = {event_abi_to_log_topic(_): _ for _ in event_abi}
        log_ = {
            'address': None, #Web3.toChecksumAddress(address),
            'blockHash': None, #HexBytes(blockHash),
            'blockNumber': None,
            'data': log['data'], 
            'logIndex': None,
            'topics': [HexBytes(_) for _ in log["topics"]],
            'transactionHash': None, #HexBytes(transactionHash),
            'transactionIndex': None
        }
       
        try:
            event_abi_entry = topic2abi[log['topics'][0]]
            if isinstance(event_abi_entry, dict):
                event_name = event_abi_entry.get('name', 'DefaultNmae')
                data = get_event_data(w3.codec, event_abi_entry, log_)['args']
                print(f"     {event_name} {data.get('value', '')}")
            elif isinstance(event_abi_entry, list):
                for abi_entry in event_abi_entry:
                    event_name = abi_entry.get('name', 'DefaultName')
                    data = get_event_data(w3.codec, abi_entry, log_)['args']
                    print(f"     {event_name} {data.get('value', '')}")
            else:
                print("Event ABI entry is not in the expected format.")
        except KeyError as e:
            exit('ABI event not found!')
print()
print("loop completed")
```

Here are the current versions of the software and libraries in use:

```
Python 3.11.6

Name: web3
Version: 6.15.1

Name: eth-utils
Version: 4.0.0

Name: hexbytes
Version: 0.3.1
```

I also test the app on Kaggle and here is the successful result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you please upload full reproducible example? I'm getting the same error and can not catch list abi, only dicts

Comment: @sirjay i did with the versions of packages

Comment: I copied this code, made fresh conda install with that versions and get `ABI event not found!`. I don't know why results are different. Let's check: the error is on `event_abi_entry = topic2abi[log['topics'][0]]` row. Can you trace 3rd transaction, what is `log['topics'][0]` value? I got `KeyError: HexBytes('0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef')`. Moreover, I see that this value has all other `log['topics'][0]` in 1st and 2nd transactions (I did `print(log['topics'][0].hex()`)

Comment: `topics [0] = b'\xdd\xf2R\xad\x1b\xe2\xc8\x9bi\xc2\xb0h\xfc7\x8d\xaa\x95+\xa7\xf1c\xc4\xa1\x16(\xf5ZM\xf5#\xb3\xef'`

Comment: when i called `hex()` method, `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

Comment: Man, I don't know, it does not work, I copied all your steps how to reproduce

Comment: I executed the same code on `Kaggle` and I dont get any error. the only difference is api key but i dont know how this will cause the error

Comment: that's impossible. Besides my Mac OS, I tested also on Windows, removed API key and left only 3rd transaction. I uploaded screenshot to the post with results.

Comment: I added the proof of successful execution on kaggle.

Comment: In kaggle I got it compiled finally. Any ideas why it does not work on 2 (!) different PCs (Mac and Windows)?

Comment: Package versions? Or try to execute the file with ‘python3.11’

Comment: All packages are the same as yours. Look at my windows screenshot, I printed there packages.

Comment: I need to have these machines to see why

Comment: Hi, can you please check your code once again? I'm compiling it on kaggle, it compiles, but anyway I can't get Transfer() value. `topic [0]` everywhere is equal, that's correct as on your screenshot. But anyway on the last transaction there is not topic like this in `topic2abi` list. So I can see `Transfer()` function on ABI, but it's topic hex is different, that's why I can not get it and figure out `value`. You compiled script as answer, but did not read `Transfer` values.

Comment: In the last transaction ABI `Transfer` hex is `e19260aff97b920c7df27010903aeb9c8d2be5d310a2c67824cf3f15396e4c16`, but it must be `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`. This is the problem.

Comment: I clearly described problem once again here if that helps: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/1b9xfc1/etherscans_abi_and_transaction_receipt_topic0_are/

Comment: do you have full project code?

Comment: No. A guy in reddit comments above helped me. There is a solution. Your answer in this topic is wrong about `dict` and `list`